# Displaying bash array

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a array
printf 'Matrix size:' ;
read n;
printf '\n';
      for ((i=1;i<=n;i++))
        do
      for((j=1;j<=n;j++))
        do
          printf 'x[%d][%d]=' ${array[i][j]};
          read array[i][j];
     done
     done
     echo "Initial matrix:"
        for((i=1;i<=$n;i++))
          do 
        for ((j=1;j<=n;j++))
          do
       printf '%d' ${array[i][j]};
           printf '\n';
        done
        done
```

A can't display bash array and don't understand where is my mistake.
For example I have: n=3....I enter numbers in array (1-9)
When I displaying:
Initial matrix:
3
3
3
6
6
6
9
9
9
Thx

Answer (score 5):

bash doesn't have multidimensional arrays; when you reference `array[i][j]`, the `[j]` is ignored. bash also has other limitations that tend to make it unsuitable for this sort of thing, such as not supporting floating point math (natively, anyway).

If you need to fake a multidimensional array in bash, you can fake it by using `array[i*n+j]` to store array[i][j]:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a array
read -p 'Matrix size: ' n
for ((i=1; i<=n; i++)); do
    for ((j=1; j<=n; j++)); do
        read -p "x[$i][$j]=" array[i*n+j]
    done
done

echo "Initial matrix:"
for ((i=1; i<=n; i++)); do 
    for ((j=1; j<=n; j++)); do
        printf '%d ' ${array[i*n+j]}
    done
    printf '\n'
done
```

Note that I've done some additional cleanup on your code:

- Don't put semicolons at the end of a line, they're redundant in a shell script.
- Print prompts with `read -p` instead of `printf`.
- The input loop was printing array[i][j] (i.e. the array's contents) where it should've printed i and j.
- You don't need to use `printf` to interpolate variables in a string, just embed `$i` in a double-quoted string (or use `${i}` to avoid ambiguity about where the end of the variable name is).
- Finally, when printing the array I made it put a newline after each row, rather than after each element.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use bash 4's associative arrays to get multidimensional arrays... sorta:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A array

printf "Matrix size: "
read -r n
for ((i = 0; i < n; i++)); do
    for ((j = 0; j < n; j++)); do
        printf "array[$i][$j] = "
        read -r val
        array["${i}_${j}"]=$val
    done
done

echo "Initial matrix:"
for key in "${!array[@]}"; do
    val=${array[$key]}
    echo "$key $val"
done
```

However, there is no true multidimensional array support available in bash.

Unlike the answer using standard numerically-indexed arrays, this approach doesn't require the dimensions of the array to be known before it can be read.

Answer (score 0):

All of Gordon's remarks are absolutely correct, for the sake of completeness I'll just add that `ksh93` (I am not certain about `ksh88`) *does* support multidimensional arrays (but it's a notoriously un(der)documented feature), so you can do this natively with `ksh`:

`matrix.sh`:

```
#!/bin/ksh

printf "Matrix size: "
read n
for ((i = 0; i < n; i++)); do
        for ((j = 0; j < n; j++)); do
                printf "array[$i][$j] = "
                read array[i][j]
        done
done

echo "Initial matrix:"
for ((i = 0; i < ${#array[@]}; i++)); do
        for k in "${array[i][@]}"; do
                printf "${k} "
        done
        echo
done
```

Example:

```
$ ./matrix.sh
Matrix size: 2
array[0][0] = 3
array[0][1] = 4
array[1][0] = 5
array[1][1] = 6
Initial matrix:
3 4
5 6
```